# CORS request failing in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I'm new to Angular and am trying to build a simple app. I keep getting this error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/student/Desktop/mvp/client/app/tradeanalyzer/tradeanalyzer.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

What do I need to do to escape this error? I did the following in my express file but it still did not work:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var cors = cors = require('cors')
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: need to open your page from http server not from file protocol. Can't do ajax from file protocol. Or, you are pointing ajax at file protocol and not using web path

Comment: Does that mean serve it in the express file? how would I do that?

Comment: what port is server running on? open that same port in localhost. Not really clear what cheerio has to do with this though either

Comment: got it.  now I get a different error which I'll post a different question for!

Comment: what's the error? Also ...shouldn't need cors for working local unless you are running api on different port from page load server